# Laravel 9 Azure Storage Blob Server AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-blob-storage, sas-token

im doing an Laravel 9 project, where i store image on azure accout.
I use this library https://github.com/matthewbdaly/laravel-azure-storage.

I try to connect with SAS Token it works but i got AuthorizationPermissionMismatch when i try to read it :

```
Route::get('/azure-test', function() {
$path = '';

$disk = \Storage::disk('azure');

$files = $disk->files($path);

dump($files);exit;
}
```

My configuration :

```
 'driver'    => 'azure',
         'driver'    => 'azure',
        'sasToken'  => env('AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN'),
        'container' => env('AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER'),
        'url'       => env('AZURE_STORAGE_URL'),
        'prefix'    => null,
        'endpoint'  => env('AZURE_STORAGE_ENDPOINT'),
        'retry'     => [
            'tries' => 3,
            'interval' => 500,
            'increase' => 'exponential'
        ],
```

Just to be clear the file exist, i test it without SAS token configuration it display informations about my test file. I already searched and did some change, like assigned my account to roles "Storage Blob Data Contributor” and “Storage Queue Data Contributor", my sas token still work when i try to see my file "https://xxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container_name/im_test_file.pdf?sp=r&st=2022-06-24T15:32:22Z&se=2024-04-30T23:32:22Z&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=QSz6SZ6UrSMg0jqyKEr4bnnGqrMuxK2EIbGgTTbP%2F10%3D" it works.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***AFAIK, To resolve "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" error try assigning [Storage Blob Data Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-reader) role to your account like below:***

[image]

> **Please **note** that Azure role assignments can take up to five
> minutes to propagate.**

**Check whether you have given the below permissions while creating the SAS token:**

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Authorize access to blobs with AzCopy & Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory#verify-role-assignments)

[Fixed – authorizationpermissionmismatch Azure Blob Storage – Nishant Rana's Weblog](https://nishantrana.me/2020/11/23/fixed-authorizationpermissionmismatch-azure-blob-storage/)